# A slowly cloning atom?

Tags: hard-science

There is a single atom of handwavium which then splits into another atom of handwavium every hour (the second atom also has the clone ability).

my question is how many hours would it take for these atoms to reach roughly the same size as earth, the sun, our solar system, and our galaxy assuming they have roughly the same room temperature density and mass as an atom of lead.

Comment: Why are you asking us a basic math question? Not saying I won't answer it, just saying you should be able to do this easily enough with a little research. Also "size" as in physical volume or mass?

Comment: "what is the 3rd person of the verb to be on the ISS?" is not a space exploration question, as much as this is not a worldbuilding question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just exponential growth.

ending count = starting count * (1 + rate)<sup>time</sup>

Where rate is 0.5 and ending count is the number of atoms in the Earth. I calculated it would take 5-6 days to each the size of the Earth but it would probably collapse into a black hole from the weight before reaching the size of the sun. Unless the cloning process creates an opposing force like heat that pushes the atoms apart to prevent gravitational collapse you won't get very far.

Comment: You bring up an interesting point.  The equation is simplistic in that it's simply dealing with the count of atoms.  As those atoms expand, they will begin to compress under their own weight, generating heat, possibly leading to different material states of the atoms.  That has wonderfully complex possibilities for "fun with physics" worlbuilding!